# Running an && after an executable

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I was trying to run the following as a one-liner to see the output of a c program:

```
$ gcc -o hi.o hi.c && ./hi.o && echo $?
```

However, that doesn't "return" or print anything. And the `echo $?` only works if I do that on a new line. For example:

```
$ gcc -o hi.o hi.c && ./hi.o
$ echo $?
21 # correct program output
```

Why does this behavior occur? What happens after the `./hi.o` that (seems to) suppress output after it?

Comment: What is the exit status of `hi.o` ? Does the compilation succeeds? (what is the content of `hi.c`?) `the echo $? only works` What does it print? `0`? or nonzero?

Comment: Note that the suffix `.o` is usually for [*object* files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_file), not executable files.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks -- what's the most common output format then for a c file (I thought that was mostly arbitrary?) -- I think without specifying anything I get `a.out`.

Comment: @KamilCuk -- it returns the int `21` from main.

Comment: On Linux (and other POSIX systems) executables typically don' have any suffix at all. See e.g. the `gcc`  command, which is a normal runable programs like many other commands.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably one of the previous commands failed (had a nonzero exit code). `&&` works like in most program languages, it short-circuits. So if I write `true && false && true`, the last `true` command is never run because the `false` command returned a non-success exit code.

(There is also `||` which does the opposite: it runs the right-hand side only if the left-hand side failed.)

According to your question, `./hi.o` returned exit code 21 which is nonzero, so it is considered as failed and the `echo $?` is not executed.

To *unconditionally* chain commands, use `;` instead:

```sh
gcc -o hi.o hi.c; ./hi.o; echo $?
```

You can also make it so that `hi.o` will run only when `gcc` succeeded, as it was before, but then in any case run the `echo`:

```sh
gcc -o hi.o hi.c && ./hi.o; echo $?
```

(This works without parentheses because [`;` has a lower precedence than `&&`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Lists.html).)

Comment: thanks for this extensive answer. I think my issue was that the `c` program was returning a non-zero status ("21" in my case) and it treats non-zero as an error.